# How to use python urllib to search in search box?

Tags: python, urllib

I'm looking to use urllib to search in the search box of https://bigfuture.collegeboard.org

Here's what I have but it's just giving me the homepage html:

```
import requests
from urllib import urlopen
from urllib import urlencode
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://bigfuture.collegeboard.org"
data = urlencode({'q': 'financial analyst'})
results = requests.post(url, data)
soup = BeautifulSoup(results.content, 'html.parser').encode("ascii", "ignore")

output = open('text.txt','w')
output.write(soup)
```

How do I use and submit to the search box?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the `/sitesearch` endpoint in your url. If I search for "uconn", the URL that the site hits is:

```
https://bigfuture.collegeboard.org/sitesearch?q=uconn&searchType=bf_site&tp=bf_site
```

So all you need to do is change your url to:

```
url = "https://bigfuture.collegeboard.org/sitesearch"
```

Also make sure you're closing your file object or using the context manager `with`!!

Answer (score 0):

Just use the query parameter in the semantic url

E.G.

```
searches = ['test','new search']

for search in searches:
    search = search.replace(' ','+')
    url = 'https://bigfuture.collegeboard.org/sitesearch?q=%s&searchType=bf_site&tp=bf_site' % (search)
    print url
    requests.get(url)
```